# Copy File Using RunDll32.exe Kernel32.dll

Tags: windows, file, api, copy

My problem is I don't know how to use CopyFile with Kernel32.

```
rundll32.exe kernel32.dll,CopyFileA "C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.txt","C:\Users\User\Desktop\test2.txt", 0
```

I am not using any program, I just want to run that command from "run" dialog if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `rundll32` to call `CopyFileA` because `CopyFileA` is not compatible. You can only use `rundll32` to call entry points with this signature:

```
void CALLBACK EntryPoint(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, 
    int nCmdShow);
```

The details for `rundll32`, including the above information, are to be found [over on MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787).

Instead of this you can, for instance, use the command interpreter with the `copy` command at the run dialog:

```
cmd /c copy file1.txt file2.txt -y
```

Comment: Your command only works from cmd not run dialog, btw my goal is to copy file hiddenly without any other files, just one command but it seems hard.

Comment: I'm wondering what you are looking for here. You ask about rundll32 and I've shown why you cannot use that. What more do you need?